# "Cannot match any routes" error when using auxiliary outlet

Tags: angular

I am trying to access a component using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/reset/finish?key=26983684729750581998` url.

The route configuration gives `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'reset/finish'`:

```
export const passwordResetFinishRoute: Route = {
    path: 'reset/finish',
    component: PasswordResetFinishComponent,
    outlet: 'loginOutlet'
};
```

Following is my router-outlet configuration:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="loginOutlet></router-outlet>
```

I am sure that I am importing the route configuration. Because when I remove `outlet: 'loginOutlet'` part, the component is displayed in primary router.

What is the reason Angular cannot find the route configuration when outlet is provided?

Answer (score -1):

There is a huge difference in these routes. The first one is a route with child route and the second one is a named component based route without child rote.

For the first one, you are telling to load the route as children of the outlet. So once the routing is done, inside the route it will search for `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and will load `PasswordResetFinishComponent` there.

As there is no name mentioned and routing is '', it will load inside as a child route. so it will be directly loaded

`<router-outlet> 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</router-outlet>`.

But for the second one, as it's a named router outlet `loginOutlet`. So it will find for `<router-outlet name='loginOutlet'></router-outlet>` and will load the component into it.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can you clarify it a little bit more? You state that, 1st one loads in primary outlet but it isnt loaded. It gives an error as stated in the question. Even though 1st one is a blank route, notice that it has a parent.

Comment: I modified the answer, see if it make sense

Comment: In Angular, there isn't a connection between parent-child relationship of route configuration with router-outlets. It doesn't mean a child route should be displayed inside a child of parent router-outlet.